# Использование lodash mixin в typescript, angular cli среде

Tags: angular2, typescript, lodash, mixins, angular-cli

Всем привет, не могу разобраться как правильно задекларировать мой добавленный с помощью миксины в `lodash` метод.
Установил lodash и @types/lodash, код компилится, базовые lodash методы подтягиваются.
Использую angular cli, в сгенеренный `typings.d.ts` добавил

```
declare module _ {
   interface LoDashStatic {
      humanize(str: string): string;
   }
}
```

Ошибка следующая: `Property 'humanize' does not exist on type 'LoDashStatic'`. Т.е. компилятор его все равно не видит.
Саму миксину положил в `src/initializers/lodash.js`. Путь к данному файлу прописал в `scripts` ключе файла `angular-cli.json`.

Comment: В общем добавил данную инструкцию в typings.ts и соответственно создал custom-typings в которую кладу свои кастомные декларации
"files": [
    "./src/custom-typings/lodash-mixins.d.ts"
  ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В англоязычной версии нашел исчерпывающее описании работы typings

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222162/typescript-2-custom-typings-for-untyped-npm-module